# iOS Swift 5 unable to disable button in custom view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, custom-view

I have a custom view with two buttons, the custom view has an associated `UIView` class file.

The idea is `button2` is disabled until `button1` is pressed and then once it (`button2`) is pressed `button2` is disabled.

Note that by disabled I mean interaction is disabled *and* the buttons is greyed out.  The odd thing is that interaction *is* being disabled but the button *isint* being greyed out

I am using `button2.isEnabled = false` this worked perfectly when the buttons were part of the main view, but since refactoring the buttons into a custom view I seem to be unable to disable the button (grey out the button).  The custom view provides a nice separation of concerns so I dont want to loss it.

I do seem to be able to set the titles of the buttons as required so I believe I have the buttons `IBOutlet` defined correctly.

The `@IBAction` for the buttons are being triggered correctly.

Rather interestingly in interface builder shows the button in a non-greyed out state even though `enabled` is deselected in the property inspector.

Thanks

```
class ControlPanelView: UIView {   
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    
    @IBAction func button1Action(_ sender: Any) {
        button2.isEnabled = true
    }
    
    @IBAction func button2Action(_ sender: Any) {
        button2.isEnabled = false
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ControlPanelView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        
        // button is still enabled
        button2.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Note this is a Storyboard project in Xcode 11 targeted at iOS 10 and above.

Comment: share your code please ...

Comment: @jawadAli I have added code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Gavin - is the Button Type `System` or `Custom`? Did you change the default Text Color?

Comment: @DonMag the button type is `System` and the Text Color is `Custom`, which is set via properties and then never changed.  That is an interesting thought, as the last change I made after confirming the refactor had worked was to swap the colours of the buttons (original button1 was blue and button2 was red) I think the original colour of button two was a System colour, I will have a play with that, bit odd they should be linked like that though, it suggests you can grey out any custom colour.

Comment: Also I am using FontAwsome as the font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is anything wrong with your code.

When you select a color other than the default for a `UIButton`, you also need to select a color for the **Disabled** state.

Select Default Text Color:

[image]

Change State Config to Disabled and select a Text Color:

[image]

Now, in Storyboard, you can see the difference when you toggle the Enabled checkbox:

[image]

[image]

(I selected Blue for Disabled just to make it clear it's not using the "default gray")

Comment: So basically I got lucky originally because I was using the default colours!!  I did notice the different state configs but didnt think to look deeper into them.  Not that its an excuse but there are so many options its hard to know whats important.  I have learnt two things, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I tried it in Xcode. Got the same issue. I solved the problem using this

```
private func commonInit() {
    ...
    // button is still enabled
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.001) {
        button2.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Let me know if it is helpful.

Comment: unfortunately this didnt work for me, thanks for trying

Comment: What about `DispatchQueue.main.async {button2.isEnabled = false}`? This should be the case for actions affecting the user interface.